# SP 2013 Site collection Master page Error: Your master page doesn't have any warnings or errors. Reset the preview to its original state

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-addin

I was trying to change a Master page on a site collection, but I keep getting the above error. Even when I revert to the default master page, the content of the site collection will not display.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the master page preview screen. You should close the tab and type in the URL.

Its really confusing, I am not sure why there is no button to exit preview mode.

**Update**

If you are still facing issue. Then restore a previous version as explained on this thread [Stuck in "Preview Page" mode in SharePoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/91660/stuck-in-preview-page-mode-in-sharepoint-2013)

Comment: Hi Amal, thanks for a reply. The page loads to a preview even when I type in the url.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by a workaround. I created another front page of the site collection and set it as a home page. Not too proud of it but since the version history in designer is not giving my access(it says :"server too busy"), I had to do it this way. This can be closed now.

Thanks